# Cannot assign a substring from a file to my array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a file with 50 states and capitals in this format:

Alabama,Tallahasee,

Wisconsin,Madison,

........

I am trying to assign the states and capitals to seperate arrays and I am having a problem with the for loop.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StatesAndCapitals {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("capitals.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(is);
    String[] states = new String[50];
    String[] capitals = new String[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
        int a = states[i].lastIndexOf(",");
        String states1 = states[i].substring(0, a);
        states[i] = states1;
        input.nextLine();
    }//end for loop

    System.out.println(states);

}
```

}

The error I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StatesAndCapitals.main(StatesAndCapitals.java:12)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
states[i].lastIndexOf(",");
```

you're analyzing the content of `states[i]`. But that is your destination array, and not the source containing the text. The source is what is returned from `input.nextLine()`, which should be the first thing you should do at each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
    String currentLine = input.nextLine();
    // now extract the data from current line, and store them in the arrays.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for an object is `null`.

```
String[] states = new String[50]; //<-- you declare an array that can holds 50 Strings but they're actually null if you don't initialize them.
```

So when doing `states[i].lastIndexOf(",");` it throws a NPE.

Same behavior for your `capitals` array.

Read the [Default Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) section.

---

You need to store the datas in a `String` variable first :

```
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
        String data = input.nextLine();
        // Now process with data and add corresponding parts to states and capitals array
    }//end for loop
```

And then process on this `String` and add it to the corresponding array.

Not that if you don't have enough lines in your file (less than 50), it will throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException` because no more lines are found.

You can add this condition to the loop : `for (int i = 0; i < states.length && input.hasNextLine(); i++){`

When you will get this working correctly, I suggest you to deal with a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
    int a = states[i].lastIndexOf(",");
    String states1 = states[i].substring(0, a);
    states[i] = states1;
    input.nextLine();
}//end for loop
```

This whole loop is backwards. When you first enter at `i = 0` you attempt to take a substring of your `states` array which has never seen any sort of assignment. You then work on that substring within the loop before *ending* with `input.nextLine();` which is never actually used.

The `input` variable, when used correctly will actually hold data from the file you open and will allow you to manipulate strings with `substring`. You need to reorder and fix your loop.